# Why is there compileSdkVersion in manifest file?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

Everywhere it is written that `compileSdkVersion` only needs to compile and isn't included in manifest file. But i opened manifest file in apk and saw `android:compileSdkVersion="32"` there. For what purposes is it there ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

> The user-visible SDK version (ex. 26) of the framework against which the application was compiled. This attribute is automatically specified by the Android build tools and should NOT be manually specified.

So there is absolutely no need or purpose for it to be present in your manifest file.

Comment: Can you give the link pls